# Why does this infinitesimal transformation tell us the boson vectors carry charge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, charge, gauge-theory, group-theory, yang-mills

I'm studying from "Cheng, Li - Gauge theory of elementary particle physics", and in section 8.1, where it talks about non-Abelian gauge symmetry and the theory you can construct imposing local $SU(2)$ symmetry, considering infinitesimal transformations, the book arrives at this infinitesimal transformation law for the boson vectors $A_{\mu}^i(x)$:

$$A_{\mu}^i{'}(x)=A_{\mu}^i(x)+\varepsilon^{ijk}\theta^jA_{\mu}^k(x)-\frac{1}{g}\partial_{\mu}\theta^i(x)\tag{8.28}$$

where $\vec{\theta}(x)$ is the vector of the parameters of the $SU(2)$ local transformation.

Then, the book says:

> The second term is clearly the transformation for a triplet (the adjoint) representation under $SU(2)$. Thus the $A_{\mu}^i$s carry charges, in contrast to the
> Abelian gauge field.

**I don't understand this sentence. why does this equation implies that these fields carry charge?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. More generally, the generators $$Q_a=R(T_a)\tag{1}$$ of global (=$x$-independent) gauge transformations $$\phi^{\prime}= e^{i\theta^a Q_a}\phi\tag{2}$$ of a field $\phi$ are associated with its (Noether) charges.

   Here $T_a$ are Lie algebra basis, and $R$ denotes a representation.

   Noether's theorem proves charge conservation.
   Conversely, the charges generate global gauge symmetries.
2. Li Cheng is in eq. (8.28) considering infinitesimal gauge transformations of gauge field $A_{\mu}$ in the adjoint representation. The third term drops out for global gauge transformations, so eq. (8.28) becomes of the form of eq. (2).
3. Alternatively, the charges (1) also appear in the Feynman rules for cubic vertices, which lead to non-Abelian generalizations of repulsion/attraction between charges.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, could you be more explicit and simplify it for me?

Comment: Remember that by the the "charge" of a particle under a non-abelian symmetry group we mean  the *representation* of the  group under which the fields transform. It is not usually a simple number as it is when the grouo is abelain and so all representations are one dimensional.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Right.

Comment: @mikestone thanks, I am a Physics student and I'm very new to non abelian gauge theories and I know nothing about group theory and representations, so I'm finding a little difficult understanding this. The only gauge theory I studied is QED.

Comment: @Rhino: If you want to study gauge theories, group representation theory  is an essential. Tony Zee's "Group theory in a Nutshell" is probably a good place to start.